# React Native: Fix view width

Tags: react-native

I want to put two view with 4:6 width in my app, and put text inside them.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View , Text} from 'react-native';

class FixedDimensionsBasics extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: "row"}}>
        <View style={{flex:0.4, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}>
          <Text>sfasdfadsfdasfas</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex:0.6, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}}>
            <Text>sfasdfadsfdasfas</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => FixedDimensionsBasics);
```

I want it like this
[image: I want it like this]

but when I add text in side, it becomes like this
[image: but when I add text in side, it becomes like this]

Question: Is there a way to keep the view with fixed width and make text adjust with the width?

Thanks!

p.s. I use the [React Native Doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width.html) for code example & debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found an answer. Using `flexBasis:0.4`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View , Text} from 'react-native';

class FixedDimensionsBasics extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: "row"}}>
        <View style={{flex:0.4, flexBasis:0.4, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}>
          <Text>sadfsfsdfasdfdsfasdsadfasdf</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex:0.6, flexBasis:0.6, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}}>
            <Text>fasddfsadfsaf</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => FixedDimensionsBasics);
```

Then the view fixed with 0.4 width. [image]

Here is the description for flex-base in CSS [CSS trick flex-base](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)