# Create A view with fixed percentage of width in all orientations in React-Native

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I want to create a view - that contains a Card - always with `'90%'` width of the window, whenever the device is vertical or horizontal, or Component is in a parent or not.

**What I tried:**

1 Using percentage

( `width: '90%'`):

It works well if I use my card separately on the main view of my screen, but when I use my card on a  horizontal `ScrollView` with other cards I can see many cards, but I want to see only one card before scrolling.

#### 2  Using `React.Dimensions`

( `Dimensions.get('window').width*0.9` with some padding) :

It works perfectly when I use a card separately or even with many inside a scrollView but when I change the orientation of the screen it takes less width of the screen than '90%'.

3 Using flex basis based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42956628/2754195)

Is there any better way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look at this package https://github.com/marudy/react-native-responsive-screen
This package doesn't require any orientation change support. It's just one file actually, so you might wanna take a look at that